# How to say "Stay where you are" in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I'm writing a kind of a little senario. A child was running. There was a stone in the road so he felt. His leg hurt. A doctor was passing by and said:

> You will be okay. You just need to sit here and have a little rest for
>   a few minutes.

I'm not sure if the doctor should say: You need to **stay sitting** here. As the boy is already sitting on the ground because of his leg hurting. Is the word **rest** good? or Is it should be used in situations like an athlete who has been training for a long time for example? Does the sentence, in general, mean that the boy shouldn't move and stay where he is for a few minutes.

I know that this is not good medical advice but it has its purpose :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written conveys what you want, especially since you're talking to a child. A phrase like "have a little rest" is very informal, which suits the setting; "a little rest" is the kind of phrase I imagine being used only to children, or to adults who are ill.

A more formal way to say "have a little rest for a few minutes" would be "rest for a little while" (without specifying a time) or simply "have a rest for a few minutes". A much more formal way would be "don't exert yourself for the next few minutes".

So your sentence is absolutely fine.

---

By the way, you said "he's leg hurts him". The possessive form of "he" is "his", and in English, your body doesn't usually "hurt itself": the transitive use of "hurt" is reserved for external objects doing somebody harm. If some part of the body is in pain, it simply "hurts". So "His leg hurts" would be a more precise way to phrase "he's leg hurts him".

Comment: wow thank you so much :)